# How to display array of objects in formData

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, form-data

Having issue to display a array of

```
    <form id="order">
        <div id="product-details">
            <div class="items">
                <input value="34324324234234234" readonly class="sku" name="sku"/>
                <input value="1" readonly id="quantity" name="quantity"/>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <input value="3242342342" readonly id="sku" name="sku"/>
                <input value="3" readonly class="quantity" name="quantity"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <button class="bn btn-primary" type="submit">Create Order</button>
    </form>
```

JS :

```
const formEL = document.querySelector('#order')

    formEL.addEventListener('submit', ev => {
        ev.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(formEL)

        const sku = formData.getAll('sku')
        const quantity = formData.getAll('quantity')
        const items = []

        for (let i = 0; i < sku.length; i++) {
            formData.append('items', items.push({
                sku: sku[i],
                quantity: quantity[i]
            }))
        }
        
        console.log(items)

        const data = Object.fromEntries(formData)
        
        console.log(data)
    })
```

When I console log the `items` it gives me array of objects of it:

[image]

but the `data` console log differently:

[image]

How can i get the array of objects from the `items` array and console it?

Comment: `formData` output correct  in my side based on your code

Comment: but why when i console log 'data' it gives me '2' instead the whole info of the array? @lucumt

Comment: @zalala, Check this forked example https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoajbrJ . Move the `formData.append('items', ...)` outside the for loop. And to append array of objects, make it stringified and then using the key you can parse and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The `push` function will return the array length, [the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value). your `items` array length is `2`. so the value of the item will be `2` in your `data`.

```
items.push({
   sku: sku[i],
   quantity: quantity[i]
})
```